# Implement the enhanced conversions script before or after conversion call

Tags: gtag.js

I am setting up *enhanced conversions* for Google Ads. I have a conversion script (works), but now I want to know where do I put this data? Before or after the `gtag('event', 'conversion')`. I cannot find this in the docs or online anywhere...

Does this script need to be placed **before** or **after** the `gtag('event', 'conversion')` call?

```
<script>
gtag('set', 'user_data', {
"email": "{{ yourEmailVariable }}",
"phone_number": "{{ yourPhoneVariable }}"
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm also struggling with this.. tagassstiant is not showing any data from the user_data for me. I am also unclear if the variable should be surrounded by double curly brackets or just double quotes? they seem to switch between the two in the documentation

Comment: I believe it should be before the actual event. However, even after three long calls with support, I never got it to work. You need to replace the quoted double curly bracket content with your own code to get the actual email and phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I deleted my old conversion tag from Google Ads, and recreated it with the javascript option. And it seems to work now, I did it like this:

On my thankyou page I have this:

```
<head>

<script>
        var enhanced_conversion_data = {
            "email": "email@email.com",
            "phone": "+3160000000000"
        };
</script>


<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxx"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }

    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-xxxx', {
        'anonymize_ip': true
    });
    gtag('config', 'AW-xxx', {
        'allow_enhanced_conversions': true
    });
</script>

<script>
    gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AW-xxx/xxxx',
        'value': 100.00,
        'currency': 'EUR',
        'transaction_id': 'invoice id or somethong'
    });
</script>

</head>
```

This seems to work for me... Within Google Ads I configured it like this

- Select Javascript/CSS option
- Check Email/Phone (or more)
- Dropdown select Javascript
- In the Email-field add this: enhanced_conversion_data.email
- In the Phone-field add this: enhanced_conversion_data.phone